# Yii 2 проверка на авторизированного пользователя его id

Tags: php, yii2

Нужен совет правильно я сделал проверку 
в layouts.php

```
if(empty(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)):
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
endif;

$validate = new SignupForm();
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
} elseif(empty($validate->validates())) {
    return Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/login']);
}
```

или это нужно делать в другом мести ? у меня по id пользователя выводиться информация которая должен видеть конкретный пользователь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> у меня по id пользователя выводиться информация которая должен видеть
>   конкретный пользователь.

Для этих целей в Yii 2 есть механизм ролей и прав доступа. С его использованием всё сводится к использованию метода `can` (почитать можно [здесь](http://streletzcoder.ru/nastraivaem-dostup-k-web-prilozheniyu-na-osnove-roley-yii-2-chast-1-obshhie-mehanizmyi-rabotyi/) и [здесь](http://streletzcoder.ru/nastraivaem-dostup-k-web-prilozheniyu-na-osnove-rolej-yii-2-chast-3-razresheniya/)).

Если определяется разграничение просто между зарегистрированными и незарегистрированными пользователями, то тогда следует использовать метод `isGuest`.

Неправильно:

```
if(empty(Yii::$app->user->identity->id)) {
    // Делаем что-то
}
```

Правильно:

```
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    // Делаем что-то
}
```

Comment: Спасибо  за помощь, но правильно ли делать такую проверку `if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    // Делаем что-то
}` layouts.php ?

Comment: Такие проверки делаются везде, где это нужно. Механизм стандартный.